# css3 transition does not trigger on DOMContentLoaded

Tags: css-transitions, domcontentloaded

Consindering the following simple example, I wonder why CSS3 transition effect is not triggered when using
DOMContentLoaded? Using window.onload or document.onreadystatechange = "complete" will work!

I know that DOMContentLoaded does not wait for  [style] but in that case i dont reference external 
stylesheets!

The most DomReady-Engines will fall back to DOMContentLoaded if supported!
Maybe someone has some ideas or information about this issue for me!
Thank you in advance!

EXAMPLE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elem = window.document.getElementById('box1');
        elem.style.height = '400px';
        elem.style.transition = "height 1s ease-in";
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box1" style="display:block; background-color:green; position:absolute; width:400px; height:100px;" >Doesn't animate in IE, Opera, Chrome etc.. but often in FIREFOX</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: Mind mentioning how my answer doesn't solve it?

Comment: it worked with asyn execution (setTimeout) but that was not my goal

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46991428/1026

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't transitions on svg work on DOMContentLoaded without delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891628/why-dont-transitions-on-svg-work-on-domcontentloaded-without-delay)

Answer (score 1):

You should put the height change in a small `setTimeout` to assure that the transition property has applied when the line is ran

```
window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('box1');
    elem.style.setProperty("transition", "height 1s ease-in");
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.style.height = '400px';
    }, 10);
}, false);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Lp8MA/)

Comment: thanx for your input, it worked with setTimeout! But why it does trigger with onload event?

Answer (score 0):

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) says that the DOMContentLoaded event takes places without waiting for stylesheets:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading.

The MDN documentation does not state that the stylesheets, images or subframes must be external. Apparently, the DOMContentLoaded event is fired even before the locally defined stylesheets are loaded.

It appears that using setTimeout() to delay setting the desired property by a short amount of time, such as 10 ms, is enough for a browser to complete loading of stylesheets in most cases. However, using setTimeout() is clearly not a reliable method to achieve your objective because there may be cases where the complete loading of all stylesheets may exceed the timeout specified in setTimeout().

Your transition works with window.onload or document.onreadystatechange because these events are fired upon the complete loading of the window or document, including stylesheets. Therefore, you may use something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var elem = window.document.getElementById('box1');
        elem.style.height = '400px';
        elem.style.transition = "height 1s ease-in";
}, false);
```