# Best practice for including scripts, defer or execute on DOMContentLoaded event?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I know the general order of when a script executes...

According to [this](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer) `defer`ed scripts are executed before the `DOMContentLoaded` event gets fired, but do not block the page and subsequent scripts from loaded (unless they are also defered). Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

This seems like another way of including scripts and executing them after the DOM is available, so when should I use this over `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){...});`? And as of ES6, what is the best practice for executing/loading scripts after the DOM becomes available? I assume `addEventListener` is preferred over jQuery's `$(document).ready` or `window.onload` (again, correct me if I'm wrong...), but where does `defer` or other methods of loading scripts come into play?

Comment: Less code means less surface area for bugs, which is one small reason why one might prefer `defer`

Comment: Defer is used on script elements, which means you can just reference your script files easily. For more details on how defer interacts vs `DomContentLoaded`, I suggest you check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950574/are-deferred-scripts-executed-before-domcontentloaded-event

Comment: I had saw that question, unfortunately it doesn't answer my question about best practices.. when is one preferred over the other, or is there a specific case where I'd rather use defer than executing code when the dom loaded event is fired?